# xCP2.2 error during application deployment [DM_QUERY2_E_ALTER_ASPECT_INVALID_ASPECT]

Tags: documentum

I have a very simple xCP 2.2 application with only 1 form and 1 content type. When I try to deploy it with xCP Designer, I get a error like this

[DM_QUERY2_E_ALTER_ASPECT_INVALID_ASPECT]error:  "Aspect (cis_annotation_aspect) is invalid and is not found in the repository"

and deployment failed and I cannot do it. Looks like it is related to CIS (Content Intelligence Services), but I do not have this product, I do not want it, I do not have any plans to use it and I think I do not have a license at all.

How can I go forward and deploy my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I were able to reproduce the same problem. As temporal workaround it is possible to install Application twice and it will work. I am not sure if everything will work fine, but from first glance I could not find any bugs.
In other words:

- deploy application first. It will fail first, but after type is
  already installed. It is failing in post install step, when all
  changes already committed to repository.
- deploy application again and it will work.

As a permanent fix it is better to wait official patch from EMC.

P.S. To be able to use this workaround you need to use "Deployment Method" Incremental and "Data Policy" Minimal during deployment.